# Zendesk - How do we can modify "subject" based on custom filed value (enter by user ) in new request form

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-app, zendesk-sdk

In my request form, I have custom field `orderno`.

I want to concatenate the `orderno` with subject (that will be Ticket's Title).
Currently I have hide the subject field with jquery script and set some default value.

```
$('.form-field.string.required.request_subject').hide(); //hide subject
$('#request_subject').val('Insurance new request no:');
```

What I want to achieve is when user submit the request form the order no which is enter by user should be included in subject.

> e.g. orderno= 12124 subject should be like "Insurance new request
> no:12124"

Is this possible ? or what can be best alternate for this

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

---

*Answered from ZendkesK Community Moderator* *[here](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4809702452122-How-do-we-can-modify-subject-based-on-custom-filed-value-enter-by-user-in-new-request-form?page=1#community_comment_4809926276506)*

he trigger condition would be `{{custom field}}` is present and any other conditions you would need.

The action would be to notify the webhook.

The JSON would be similar to `{"ticket": {"subject": "{{ticket.title}} [{{ticket.ticket_field_yourfieldID}}]"}}`

I also add a tag and check for the tag to ensure it only fires once.

The webhook would have an endpoint of `https://yourdomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/{{ticket.id}}.json`

Request method PUT

Request format JSON

We use this method in several situations and it works very well for us

Comment: Would be simpler if I could just fill them in via URL query: `https://support.xxxx.com/hc/en-gb/requests/new?ticket_form_id=6593494948253&subject=blabla&description=bla`